# How to retrieve button ids in tictactoe game in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var table = [];
    var blocks = 9;
    var player1, player2, boardId;
    var chance = 1;
    var buttonKey;
    winningCombinations = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9],
    [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]];

    $(document).ready(function () {

        buttonId = 1;

        for (var index = 0; index < blocks; index++) {
            buttonKey = document.createElement("button");

            if ((index == 3 || index == 6)) {
                lineBreak = document.createElement('br');
                document.body.appendChild(lineBreak);
            }

            buttonKey.innerHTML = " + ";
            buttonKey.id = buttonId;
            buttonKey.setAttribute("value", buttonId);
            buttonKey.setAttribute("text", buttonId);

            buttonKey.style.fontFamily = "Times New Roman";
            buttonKey.style.backgroundSize = "50px";
            buttonKey.style.backgroundColor = "#C0C0C0";
            buttonKey.style.fontSize = "25px";
            buttonKey.style.marginBottom = "10px";
            buttonKey.style.marginLeft = "5px";
            buttonKey.style.marginRight = "5px";
            document.body.appendChild(buttonKey);
            buttonId++;



            buttonKey.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                selectMark(event, event.srcElement);
                checkIsWinner(event, event.srcElement);

            });
        }

    });

    function selectMark(currentObject, currentType) {

        if (chance % 2 != 0) {
            player1 = 'x';
            document.getElementById(currentType.id).innerHTML = player1;
            document.getElementById(currentType.id).style.backgroundColor = '#238EE1';

            console.log("player 1 -x")
        }
        else {
            player2 = 'o';
            document.getElementById(currentType.id).innerHTML = player2;
            document.getElementById(currentType.id).style.backgroundColor = '#FF1010';
            console.log("player2 - o")
        }
        chance++;
    }


    function checkIsWinner(currentObject, currentType) {

        winningCombinations = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9],
        [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]];

        var element = document.getElementById(currentType.id);
        var tie = 0;

        for (var column = 0; column < 8; column++) {


            answer1 = winningCombinations[0][column];
            answer2 = winningCombinations[1][column];
            answer3 = winningCombinations[2][column];


            if (element.innerHTML == 'x' &&
                (id == answer1 && id == answer2
                    && id == answer3)) {
                console.log("player 1 is the Winner");
                return false;
            }
            else if (element.innerHTML == 'o' &&
                (id == answer1 && id == answer2
                    && id == answer3)) {
                console.log("player 2 is the Winner");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                tie++;
                if (tie == 8) {
                    console.log("Its a Tie");
                }
                console.log(element.id);
            }
        }


    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>

 <body>
<div id="displaytable"></div>

 </body>

 </html>
```

I am creating a tictactoe game where i have 9 buttons. I have given an id to every button and added an addEventListener to the button. Now i to want to check the Winner, so i need to retrieve the button id's and find if the combination works.I have tried to retrieve using various notations it didn't work, here in this code i have posted it with buttonKey.id still its non-functional. How to retrieve that. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You just check the property id

in your function:

```
buttonKey.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            selectMark(event, event.srcElement);
            checkIsWinner(event, event.srcElement);
            var elem = event.target;
            var id = elem.id;
            //now you do what you want to do with it...
        });
```

You could declare `id` some were else to open the scope...

Comment: is your JS code in a separated file or a `<script></script>` tag?

Comment: <script> </script> tag

Comment: does it give you any errors in the console? were is your `<script></script>` tag located?